# Working with pthreads and synchronization

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, pthread-barriers

I'm writing a toy program to help me understand how barriers work. In the program I have each thread checking to see if an element in one array is in another array. I was able to have all threads start searching simultaneously but I'd like to have them all meet up after filtering in order to correctly add any numbers to the array.

Without doing so, the the wrong numbers might be added to the array.

EDIT: Someone suggested I'd add pthread_barrier_wait(&after_filtering); in the call to filter_threads and that seemed to do trick. Now I know that I have to add a wait call in main as well as in the filter function, but I don't quite understand the flow of execution and how the wait calls in main work. I know that the wait in the thread function ensures that all threads reach that point before continuing but doesn't that happen as soon as the threads created? Meaning that nums should have values of 99 instead of 4, 3, 8, 1?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_barrier_t before_filtering, after_filtering;
int nums[4] = {99, 99, 99, 99};
int arr[15] = {12, 5, 31, 8, 1, 6, 24, 4, 81, 42};

void filter(int i, int a[]){
    // Loop through the list
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        if (nums[i] == a[j])
            nums[i] = 0; 
    }
}

void *filter_threads(void *id){
    int *myid = (int *)id;
    printf("thread %d\n",*myid);
    pthread_barrier_wait(&before_filtering);
    filter(*myid, arr);
    pthread_barrier_wait(&after_filtering);
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t tids[3];
    int index[3];
    pthread_barrier_init(&before_filtering, NULL, 4);
    pthread_barrier_init(&after_filtering, NULL, 4);
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {   
        index[i] = i + 1;
        pthread_create(&tids[i], NULL, filter_threads, &index[i]);
    }

    // Cannot call any filter function without first populating nums
    nums[0] = 4;
    nums[1] = 3;
    nums[2] = 8;
    nums[3] = 1;

    pthread_barrier_wait(&before_filtering);
    filter(0, arr);
    pthread_barrier_wait(&after_filtering);

    // Add new numbers to arr...

    printf("New nums: ");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("%d, ", nums[i]);
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        pthread_join(tids[i], NULL);

    // Print new arr...

    pthread_barrier_destroy(&before_filtering);
    pthread_barrier_destroy(&after_filtering);
}
```

I tried adding another wait call after the filtering but now the program just hangs. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: @fpea You should update your question with the additional code you've added.

Comment: @fpea what exactly is your question and what are you trying to accomplish with this program? The main thread counts as a thread so as long as your total thread count (including main) is equal to the number of calls to a `barrier_wait` for a condition you make, everything will run. Now that you've added your additional call to `barrier_wait`, you should be done. The threads will wait 3 seconds for main to make the 4th and final call to `barrier_wait`, so they will not execute immediately as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

A barrier is simply a mechanism to ensure that all N threads reach a certain point in the code before continuing. Hence, if you call `pthread_barrier_init` with a count of 4, any thread calling `pthread_barrier_wait` on that same barrier will not continue until three *other* threads have also called `pthread_barrier_wait`.

So, as your code provides now: the three created threads will, once started, execute the `pthread_barrier_wait(&before_filtering)` where they will all block until after the main thread has executed `sleep(3)` and then initialized the `nums` array. The main thread then calls `pthread_barrier_wait(&before_filtering)`. This releases the main thread and all the others to continue execution.

After executing the `filter` function, each sub-thread *and* the main thread should execute `pthread_barrier_wait(&after_filtering)`. Otherwise, the main thread will be stalled waiting for three other threads to wait on the barrier.

That being said, there is no need to use the second barrier at all. At that point, the main thread is really just waiting for the other three threads to finish their task and quit. The `pthread_join` on each sub-thread being done by the main thread accomplishes the same thing: i.e. the `pthread_join` on a thread will not return until that thread has finish execution.